# MKL CBlas error

Tags: c, matrix, blas

I try to get product of two matrix say A and B into C using cblas provided by intel MKL.
Is there any reason for this to be result in error?

```
double * A, *B, *C;

A = (double *) calloc(20 * 200, sizeof (double));
B = (double *) calloc(200 * 200, sizeof (double));
C = (double *) calloc(20 * 200, sizeof (double));

cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, 
     20, 200, 200,
     1.0, A, 20,
     B, 200,
     0.0, C, 20);
```

Comment: Are *you* getting an error?  If so, what is it?

Comment: What sort of error? Compilation? Runtime? "Wrong" result?

Comment: the program terminates itself by "process terminated unexpectedly". However when I replace 20 with 2 and 200 with 3. The program works fine; gives no error.

Comment: I just get "segmentation fault".

Comment: This code looks correct to me, and running it does not give me any errors even on valgrind. I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check all the parameters to cblas_dgemm. If you have a mistake, the function could be reading beyond the bounds of the array. For small sizes that won't trigger a fault, since the bad addresses will still fall inside a single memory page. (But the math will be wrong, you should check it.) But a 200x200 matrix is 2.5 megabytes of data, passing the wrong size will definitely trigger a segfault.